# trailheadapps / lwc-recipes install failure

Tags: lwc

Deploying(https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) To a sandbox and gets following error

=== Component Failures [4]

Type   Name                    Problem

─────  ──────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Error  Contact.CleanStatus     Could not resolve standard field's name. (138:61)

Error  Account-Account Layout  In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named NewNote found

Error  Contact-Contact Layout  In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named NewNote found

Error  recipes                 In field: field - no CustomField named Contact.CleanStatus found

Answer (score 0):

Resolution

Delete following from your sfdx project
1.Contact.CleanStatus

2.Contact-Contact Layout

3.lwc-recipes\force-app\main\default\permissionsets\recipes.permissionset-meta.xml

sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app

Got to no error listed but still unable to deploy

Type  Name  Problem
────  ────  ───────

ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Deploy failed.

Comment: Only able to deploy this to scratch org. after sfdx update command